# How to run cucumber test runner using junit command line

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, cucumber

I have below project structure:

[image]

I have created a BDD test using Cucumber JUnit. I want to run these test as JUnit using command line

Test Runner :

```
package com.welcome.runner;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@launch", features = "features", glue = {"com.welcome.steps"}, plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json"})
public class TestRunner {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("This is called before");
    }

}
```

And These are dependencies in `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

While i try to execute TestRunner class using below command (navigated to project directory):

```
java -cp /Users/my.user/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13/junit-4.13.jar:hamcrest-core-2.2.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.welcome.runner.TestRunner
```

I started getting below error :

> 1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class
>   [com.welcome.runner.TestRunner]
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.welcome.runner.TestRunner

I'm not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: You should move your TestRunner class inside main/java/com/welcome/runner. That should fix the issue. As in a normal Jar, test classes are not packed. But, you will need to assemble your jar with test-classes and ensure that they exist in the jar as well.

Comment: Thanks @AvinashSagar, But its not working i moved TestRunner under main Not if i try to simply run runner file by right click it throwing error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/options/CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$OptionsProvider`

Comment: Remove scope test from the cucumber-java dependency